# How to load ace/mode/javascript and theme js files for Ace Editor in IIS Server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

This is my code

```js
var app = angular.module('editorApp', ['ui.ace']);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
    window.define = ace.define;
    $scope.aceOptions = {
          workerPath: '../../Scripts/app/vendor/',    
          useWrapMode: true,
          showGutter: true,
          theme: 'chrome',
          firstLineNumber: 1,
          onLoad: function (_editor) {
              $scope.onLoadSaveCode = "";
              var _session = _editor.getSession();
              _session.setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
              var _renderer = _editor.renderer;

              _session.on('changeAnnotation', function () {
                  $scope.annotations = [];
                  $scope.annotations = _editor.getSession().getAnnotations();
              }),
              _editor.$blockScrolling = Infinity;
              // Editor Events
              var shouldRevert = false;
              _session.on("change", function (e) {
                  var currentValue = _editor.getSession().getValue();
                  $scope.clientScriptFunction.json_meta_data = currentValue;
              });
          },
          require: ['ace/ext/language_tools'],
          advanced: {
              enableSnippets: false,
              enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
              enableLiveAutocompletion: true
          }
      };
});
```

```html
<div class="e1" ui-ace="aceOptions">
  
  </div>
```

BundleConfig.cs :-

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/dashboard").Include(
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/angular.min.js",
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/angular-sanitize.js",                
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/ace.js",    
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/ui-ace.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/app/vendor/ext-language_tools.js",
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/angular-animate.js",
           "~/Scripts/app/vendor/angular.ui-router.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/app/dashboard/app.js"
        ));
```

In the above code is worked in local . When i publish the code into IIS Server and run the project. Two Errors are occured  `Failed to load Resources theme-chrome.js and mode-javascript.js files` . I tried to created ace folder place these two files but also same issue raised so how to resolve errors , how to load these files.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got answer. 
bundling these two mode-javascript and theme-chrome js files . Then define the define in these two files like open mode-javascript and theme-chrome js files instead of `define(`  use `ace.deine(`